# Vector Matrix multiplication in python?

Tags: python, vector, matrix, multiplication

So I'm trying to multiply a matrix by a vector. And python keeps on throwing up an error. Here is the code that I'm trying:

```
def matmult(m, v):
    rows = len(m)
    w = [0]*rows
    irange = range(len(v))
    sum = 0
    for j in range(rows):
        r = m[j]
        for i in irange:
            sum += r[i]*v[i]
    w[j],sum = sum,0
return w
```

It's not mine, but that is what I coded before I got angry and deleted it. The error was this: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I'm guessing that python is seeing the vector as an int or as a list and won't do any basic operators due to the difference in types. Any way to work around this? Unfortunately I can't use Numpy.

Comment: The error was in the `sum += r[i]*v[i]` line.

Comment: It looks like `r[i] * v[i]` is a list, which probably means that `r[i]` is a list, meaning `m[j][i]` is a list. Can you print out the value of `m` that you're using?

Comment: If you have many operations to do like that, you should take a look at numpy.

Comment: in a real project you would be using [real libraries](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a different, shorter approach for pure-python matrix-times-vector multiplication:

```
 import operator
 import itertools

 def dot(x, y):
     assert len(x) == len(y)
     return sum(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.izip(x, y)))

 def matmult(m, v):
     return [dot(row, v) for row in m]
```

(This is for python 2 -- replace `itertools.izip` with just `zip` in python 3.)