# how can i do vector-matrix multiplication in python without numpy?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

Ok, so i know this question has been asked several times before but they all had different errors

so i am a newbie in python and we were given a Algebra practical with python for vector-matrix multpilication

and this was my code but i am getting a specific error everytime which is
list index out of range
line 20 in 
d=m[i][j]*v[j]

i don't really understand what is the cause of this error!

please help

Heres my code:

```
r=int(input("enter rows"))
c=int(input("enter columns"))
m=[]
for i in range(r):
    m.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        e=int(input("enter element"))
        m[i].append(e)
for i in range(r):
    print(m[i])
vm=input("enter vector [ vector matrix] \n v :")
v=[]
v=[int(x) for x in vm.split()]
print('vector v ',v)
print('Vector-Matrix multiplication:')
for i in range (c):
    re=0
    for j in range(len(v)):
        d=m[i][j]*v[j]
        re+=d
    print('[',re,']')

um=input("enter vector[ matrix -vector ]\n u :")
u=[]
u=[int(x)for x in um.split()]    
print('vector u',u)
print("matrix vector multiplication")
for i in range(r):
    res=0
    for j in range(len(u)):
        c=m[i][j]*u[j]
        res+=c
    print('[',res,']')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector Matrix multiplication in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504167/vector-matrix-multiplication-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`i` is indexing the row in `d=m[i][j]*v[j]`, but your loop is over the number of columns. You could eliminate errors like that and make the code cleaner by looping directly over the rows. Instead of `for i in range (c):` you'd have `for row in m:` and `d=row[j]*v[j]`. You should also take advantage of the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function to do the dot products. Combining these you end up replacing

```py
for i in range (c):
    re=0
    for j in range(len(v)):
        d=m[i][j]*v[j]
        re+=d
    print('[',re,']')
```

with

```py
for row in m:
    re=sum(row[j] * v[j] for j in range(v)]
    print('[',re,']')
```

If you really need an incrementing index then [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is the function that can provide it, for example:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(m):
    re=sum(row[j] * v[j] for j in range(v)]
    print(f'{i}.  [{re}]')
```

Comment: As an exercise, see if you can eliminate the `i, row` loop also, so that the matrix \* vector operation is a one-liner list comprehension that leverages the `sum` function.